# How to change two variables to values that are opposite to another

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about changing variables.

I'm making a scoreboard for table tennis. I'm trying to show the players who has to serve. Everytime the x-key gets pressed (/when a point is scored), I check if the right to serve has to change. For this example I removed that bit.

What I'm trying to do:
Everytime an input is detected (keyboard event), the opacity of the first variable is changed to be the opposite from what is was, as well as the second variable.
Perhaps, you could think of it like a railroad crossing.

What is happening:
Only the opacity of the first variable is 1. This is due to the code running from top to bottom. It sees that the currentActionPlayer1 variable is 0, so it makes it 1. But when it reaches the if statement 'currentActionPlayer2 == 0', that is true. So the currentActionPlayer1 variable becomes 0, and cAP2 becomes 1 again.

I don't really know how to explain it any better.

```js
var currentActionPlayer1 = 1;
var currentActionPlayer2 = 0;

window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp);

function checkKeyUp(keyUp) {
  if (keyUp.keyCode == "88") { //X
    changeActionPlayer();
  }
}

function changeActionPlayer() {
  if (currentActionPlayer1 == 1) {
    currentActionPlayer1 = 0;
    currentActionPlayer2 = 1;
    changeActionIcon();
  }
  if (currentActionPlayer2 == 1) {
    currentActionPlayer1 = 0;
    currentActionPlayer1 = 1;
    changeActionIcon();
  }
}

function changeActionIcon() {
  if (currentActionPlayer1 == 1) {
    document.getElementById('actionP1').style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById('actionP2').style.opacity = "0.2";
  }
  if (currentActionPlayer2 == 1) {
    document.getElementById('actionP1').style.opacity = "0.2";
    document.getElementById('actionP2').style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <p id='actionP1' style='opacity: 0.2'>action</p>
  <p id='actionP2' style='opacity: 0.2'>action</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And the problem is (besides the fact that you shouldn't be using [`.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) anymore because it has been deprecated)

Comment: @Andreas The problem is that only actionP2 gets an opacity of 1. I know why my code does that, but I don't know how to code that what I want. If I shouldnt be using .keyCode , what should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I right understand, you need something like this one?

```js
var currentActionPlayer1 = 1;
var currentActionPlayer2 = 0;

window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp);

function checkKeyUp(keyUp) {
  if (keyUp.code == "KeyX") { //X
    changeActionPlayer();
  }
}

function changeActionPlayer() {
    if (currentActionPlayer1 == 1) {
        currentActionPlayer1 = 0;
        currentActionPlayer2 = 1;
        changeActionIcon();
    } else if (currentActionPlayer2 == 1) {
        currentActionPlayer2 = 0;
        currentActionPlayer1 = 1;
        changeActionIcon();
    }
}

function changeActionIcon() {
  if (currentActionPlayer1 == 1) {
    document.getElementById('actionP1').style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById('actionP2').style.opacity = "0.2";
  }
  if (currentActionPlayer2 == 1) {
    document.getElementById('actionP1').style.opacity = "0.2";
    document.getElementById('actionP2').style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <p id='actionP1' style='opacity: 0.2'>action</p>
  <p id='actionP2' style='opacity: 0.2'>action</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I didn't know about `else if()` but it's quite obvious, actually.

Comment: pls use `(keyUp.code == "KeyX")` instead of `(keyUp.keyCode == "88")`